# ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2) in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am getting ValueError in django. Can you please help me with this. I tried several times. But Still getting this error.

models.py

```
class Parlour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name+" "+self.owner_name

class Service(models.Model):
    parlour = models.ForeignKey(Parlour,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name+" "+self.parlour.name
```

views.py

```
def parlourdetail(request,slug):
    parlourdetails = get_object_or_404(Parlour,slug)
    services = Service.objects.filter(parlour=parlourdetails)
    context = {
        'parlourdetails':parlourdetails,
        'services':services,
    }
    return render(request,'parlourapp/parlour_detail.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404) should be passed keyword arguments for the query parameters

```
parlourdetails = get_object_or_404(Parlour, slug=slug)
```

Just passing `slug` as a positional argument does not make sense, Django would not know what field to query against